# localStorage on Edge produces "An internal error occurred in the Microsoft Internet extensions"

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, runtime-error, local-storage

When a page attempts to use `localStorage`, or I enter `localStorage` in the console, Edge throws

[image: An internal error occurred in the Microsoft Internet extensions]

Using `sessionStorage` works perfectly.

I have tried reinstalling Edge with PowerShell:

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml” -Verbose}
```

But didn't solve the problem. I also read that removing navigation data could fix the problem, but attempting that also produces an error.

From [this MS answers thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/an-internal-error-occurred-in-the-microsoft/c3a186ac-4db0-46b5-b2ba-d134086bb293),

- `netsh winsock reset` completed successfully but didn't solve the problem
- The 2nd method describes how to reset IE settings, not Edge settings.

I also tried:

1. Remove `%windir%\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
2. Restore it with `sfc /scannow`
3. Reinstall Edge with the PowerShell command above

It's worth noting `sfc /scannow` tells me it was unable to some corrupt files. The log `%windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log` contains

```
Error - Overlap: Duplicate ownership for directory [l:68]"\??\C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\pris" in component Microsoft-Windows-MicrosoftEdge.Resources, version 10.0.10586.0, arch amd64, culture [l:5]"ca-ES", nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}
Error - Overlap: Duplicate ownership for directory [l:68]"\??\C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\pris" in component Microsoft-Windows-MicrosoftEdge.Resources, version 10.0.10586.218, arch amd64, culture [l:5]"en-US", nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}
```

Not sure what that "Duplicate ownership for directory" means. The Security tab says the owner is TrustedInstaller:

[image]

Comment: Edge does not support extensions at this time.  The SFC log indicates a permission problem on the Edge directory though.

Comment: @Ramhound Is `localStorage` an extension? How should the permissions be?

Comment: This appears to be a local issue... as it works fine in my machine.  Do you have another PC to verify?

Comment: @egray I have tried another PC and the CBS log shows the same error but `localStorage` works. Attempting the remove navigation data crahes Edge.

Comment: OK, so now you need to figure out what those 2 PCs have in common... perhaps a firewall, antivirus, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the problem was that my user profile was broken.

I created another profile and there it worked properly. I messed with the security privileges of that profile, and I was able to get the same problem. But I didn't manage to fix it.

Today the Windows 10 Anniversary Update (v1607) appeared in Windows Update.

After installed it, when I logged in, Windows updated my profile to work with the new version.

Somehow this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue using next approach - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-outlook_mail/cant-add-gmail-account-to-windows-10-mail-app/97d4e308-54a8-4afe-b74f-501b1ea0fa2a?page=12

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this error and I eventually tracked it down to something messed up in `~/AppData/Local/Windows/WebCache/`. When I looked there were over 20,000 files totaling about 10GB. When I deleted everything in the folder that fixed the problem. (This will likely clear most or everything stored in IE and maybe Edge.